# Set static variable in Apex based on argument passed from JS Helper

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have a static variable that would hold a Map with Ids and relevant custom objects. The map is initialized by a simple function (some SOQL calls and List to Map transform):

`public static Map<String, CustomObject__c> myMap = getMyMap()`

Later, in my Apex controller I could easily use `myMap` anywhere and get CustomObject's field from the map using a function like this:

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static String loadName(String objectId) {
    return myMap.get(objectId).Name;
}
```

The problem is that now the requirements have changed and I need to pass an argument to `getMyMap` function to make it look like `getMyMap(String otherId)`. I need to pass this *otherId* argument from JS Helper.

I wanted to created `myMap` variable like this: `public static Map<String, CustomObject__c> myMap` and add an init function that would initalize `myMap` and would be called from JS Helper:

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, FeatureType__c> initializeMap(String otherId) {
    List<CustomObject__c> objectList = getListSomehow(otherId);
    Map<String, CustomObject__c> customObjectMap = new Map<String, CustomObject__c>();

    for(CustomObject__c object: objectList){
      customObjectMap.put(object.Id, object);
    }

    //Here I wanted to set my static variable myMap
    myMap = customObjectMap;

    return customObjectMap;
}
```

I thought that would work but it seems that `myMap` variable is not initalized as I get an error: **System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object**.

I need to use this static variable in many places in my Apex Controller so I am looking for a way to initialize it once at the beginning using provided String argument passed from the JS Helper.

Is it possible?

Comment: read sfdxfox answer please https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172265/can-we-access-auraenabled-variables-in-auraenabled-methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scope of a Static variable is per transaction.

`initializeMap` is 1 transaction, `loadName` is another transaction.

The values you set in 1st transaction, won't be retrievable by the second transaction.

Anywho AuraEnabled are stateless methods, ie you are never supposed to get state from any other class level context variable unless you initizale them in your context.

I would keep it simple and delay the SOQL till the last moment. So removing `initializeMap` and just doing your operation/SOQL in `loadName` sounds more appropriate.